# Read registry key of both 32-bit and 64-bit version of an application from a 32-bit application

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, registry, cpu-architecture

I found some answers related to this topic, but could not find any that addressed my need. So, kindly help me with the below issue.

I am running a 32-bit Windows application. A part of the application code is intended to read the language(locale) of another software application from the registry (lets name this another software application as 'OtherApplication' for our discussion). 'OtherApplication' could either be a 32-bit version or 64-bit version. This C++ code looks like as follows:

```
char* DetermineLanguage(Bitness bitness)
{
    std::string keyNameStr;
    if(bitness == k64Bit)
        keyNameStr = _T("SOFTWARE\\CompanyName\\OtherApplication\\");
    else
        keyNameStr = _T("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\CompanyName\\OtherApplication\\");

    TCHAR language[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD len, type = 0;
    HKEY key = NULL;

    if ((RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyNameStr.c_str(), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &key) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        && (RegQueryValueEx(key, _T("Language"), NULL, &type, (BYTE*)language, &len) == ERROR_SUCCESS))
    {
        RegCloseKey(key);
        key = NULL;
        return language;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

I am not sure but my understanding is that the above code has some issues. First of all, I should not be creating keyName based on the bitness. Instead I should use some other Registry API that would do the redirection automatically (either to Wow6432Node or otherwise) depending on the bitness of 'OtherApplication'. In that case, this bitness information would need to be passed to that Registry API. I also realize that I need to use the flag KEY_WOW64_64KEY/KEY_WOW64_32KEY since my running code application is a 32-bit application.

Secondly, I was also not sure if this code would work fine or not on 32-bit OS, where there would be no Wow6432Node.

**What I'm looking for**:-
I am looking to get my understanding of the above concerns validated. Also, since I could not refine all of the information that I gathered to write the proper code, so I'm looking for some help/guidance here to write this code in the best possible manner. Which Registry API(s) is most suitable for my purpose? Thank you!

Comment: you not need use *WOW6432Node* - use single path *"SOFTWARE\\CompanyName\\OtherApplication"*. and with `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` and `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`

Comment: also need call `RegCloseKey` if `RegOpenKeyEx` ok, even if `RegQueryValueEx` fail. so your code is wrong in this - possible handle leak. `key = NULL;` no any sense and return address of local variable `language` fatal error.

Comment: "*I was also not sure if this code would work fine or not on 32-bit OS, where there would be no Wow6432Node*" - use `Get(Native)SystemInfo()` to determine whether the OS is 32bit or 64bit. If 32bit, force `bitness` to `k32Bit` and omit any use of the `KEY_WOW64_(32|64)KEY` flags since they don't exist on 32bit OSes

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! 

What is the effect of KEY_WOW64_(32|64)KEY on 32-bit OS? Does the API return an error? Or, it just works fine by always accessing the 32-bit registry key?  Or, is it undefined? 

Do you recommend not worrying about the native OS bitness at all, and simply call the API with either of  KEY_WOW64_(32|64)KEY  - could there be any problem with that?

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you kindly help with the question in the above comment. Thanks!

Comment: @RakeshAgarwal specifying the *correct* `KEY_WOW64_(32|64)KEY` flag is supported on XP and later. You can use only `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` on 32bit versions, and either `KEY_WOW64_(32|64)KEY` on 64bit versions, depending on whether WOW64 is installed. But prior to XP, these flags are completely unsupported and will cause the function to fail.